# Does ALS require zero entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

Does the Spark MLlib implementation of alternating least squares (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) require that all zero entries for the training set (user-product combinations where the user has no history of interacting with the product) are manually created with a rating of 0, or will the algorithm automatically imply that all missing combinations have a zero rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The training set can be sparse, and in fact, should be -- otherwise you'll pay a (possibly severe) performance penalty. See [this discussion](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/implicit-ALS-dataSet-td7067.html) on the spark users mailing list for more information.